# Issue with getting Python input to work with lowercase and uppercase input

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to input `evet`, it does not work. However, when typing `Evet`, my code runs perfectly. Is there a way to have the code work regardless of the capitalization?

`question = input("Oyunu Oynamak İstermisin [Evet/Hayır] ")`

Comment: Please show us an example with the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue. The information you provide is not enough to even begin speculate.

Comment: Where is code of your function and text of error?

Comment: question = input("Oyunu Oynamak İstermisin [Evet/Hayır] ")

Comment: If ı try to wrıte Evet ıt doest give me error but ıf ı write evet it gives me error.

Comment: Hi Baykus can you copy and paste the error that you are receiving. It helps to include your code snippits inside of ```s

Comment: It gives Syntax Error

Comment: I did the solution that @Cygnus said and it gave me a print error

Comment: We can say that Syntax Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, it would seem that your best bet is using `lower()` or `upper()`.

```
question = input("Oyunu Oynamak İstermisin [Evet/Hayır] ")
if question.lower() == "yes":
  . . . 
  . . .
```

Comment: You can replace `yes` with whatever input you want to receive.

Comment: Replace `yes` with `evet` then. Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Ok ım trying ıt now.

Comment: @Baykuş did my solution work?

Comment: It would also make the system a bit more robust to add a `.strip()` to remove any whitespace.  The `input()` function only trims the end-of-line.  Something like `question.strip().lower()`.  That way an input of "  Yes" still equals "yes"

Comment: It kinda worked...